# The element type "Linear Layout" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</Linear Layout>" help solve this error in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I keep getting this error and I'm pretty sure I have closed all the tags what might be the problem? here is my xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#73C8C0"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingVertical="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_C"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#DF0707"
                android:text="@string/c"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:cornerRadius="36dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/open_bracket"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#887E7E"
                android:text="("
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:cornerRadius="36dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/closed_bracket"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#777171"
                android:text=")"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:cornerRadius="36dp" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_divide"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ExtendedFloatingActionButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="72dp"
                android:layout_margin="12dp"
                android:backgroundTint="#FF5722"
                android:text="/"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                app:cornerRadius="36dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your xml.

Comment: From your provided xml code, there’s no starting <LinearLayout> tag before your first material button and you closed the linear layout after your last button. Make sure you entered starting linear layout tag. Or provide the whole xml file for more clearance. 
You can put your code inside the code block using ctrl+k key for more clear questions.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole code is ok but u need start a linear layout tag to end it, add this at the starting of your xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks let me check it out